# Did the Xakhun ever make it into official production sources?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, history-of-gaming

The Xakhun were a subrace of Drow, introduced in [Dragon Magazine #244](https://archive.org/stream/DragonMagazine260_201801/DragonMagazine244#page/n35/mode/2up), along with the accompanying descriptions of their airships, powered by a gemstone called Uhl. They believed that Lloth wanted them to go forth and conquer the skies, so they kidnapped and forcibly interbred with Wood Elves to get sun resistance.

I have looked through various sources and have not found any other mentions that it was continued as either a monster subrace or as a possible playable race. Is the Dragon Magazine article the only mention of the Xakhun, or was it produced in a later playable line somewhere and I've missed it?

Answer (score 5):

I’ve executed a number of web searches and trawled through quite a few results, and every single one of them refers to the xakhun as being found in *Dragon* vol. 244, and does not mention them being found anywhere else. That includes in cross-edition sources that presumably *would* mention other sources for each edition if they were available.

A *few* places mentioned *Dragon* vol. **1**44, which I presume is a typo. I don’t have a copy of that issue, though, so I cannot check.

This leads me to believe that no, they have never been mentioned again.

Comment: Just a tip - Archive.org has all the Dragon magazines available up to a certain point, just replace the 244 in the url I provided with 144 to get that edition. I don't see anything about them in that edition, so I suspect you are correct, it's a typo.